# Reverse each word of a string without altering their position(Without using inbuilt fucntion)

Tags: java, string

I want to reverse each individual word of a String in Java in different different sitautions (not the entire string, just each individual word).

Example1: if input String is "This is a test" then the output should be "sihT si a tset".

Example2: if input String is "This  is a  test" then the output should be "sihT  si a  tset".
[When there is more than one space between some words]

Please also provide algorithm for understanding

What I have tried so far

```
class reverseAString
    {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
        String str= "Test the product";
        String strArr[]= str.split(" ");


        for(int i=0;i<=strArr.length-1;i++)
        {
            for(int j=strArr[i].length()-1; j>=0;j--)
            {
                System.out.print(strArr[i].charAt(j));

            }
            System.out.printf(" ");
        }
        }
    }

---------

 public String reverseWordByWord(String str){
        int strLeng = str.length()-1;
        String reverse = "", temp = "";

        for(int i = 0; i <= strLeng; i++){
            temp += str.charAt(i);
            if((str.charAt(i) == ' ') || (i == strLeng)){
                for(int j = temp.length()-1; j >= 0; j--){
                    reverse += temp.charAt(j);
                    if((j == 0) && (i != strLeng))
                        reverse += " ";
                }
            temp = "";
        }
    }
    return reverse;
}
```

Comment: User should try before posting the question, and post what he/she has tried so far

Comment: if you want hints: Stack, spaces, push, pop.

Comment: @ankur-singhal Thanks you for letting me know, I am not avid user of stakoverflow so I don not the rules :)

Comment: Your task sucks a lot. How can you learn something about java if you wont use built-in tools?

Answer (score 0):

This approach is much more succinct.

```
class StringRev{
    public static void main(String args[]){
    String str[] = "Test the product".split(" ");
    String finalStr="";
        for(int i = str.length-1; i>= 0 ;i--){
            finalStr += str[i]+" ";
        }
        System.out.println(finalStr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String arg[]) {
    System.out.println(reverseWords("This is a test"));
}

// function to reverse each word
public static String reverseWords(String input) {
    String result = null;
    StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    String split[] = input.split(" ");
    for (String temp : split) {
        if (temp != " ") {
            strBuffer.append(reverse(temp));
            strBuffer.append(" ");
        } else {
            strBuffer.append(" ");
        }
    }

    result = strBuffer.toString();
    return result;
}

// function to reverse individual word
public static String reverse(String input) {
    StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    char[] charArray = input.toCharArray();
    for (int j = charArray.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        strBuffer.append(charArray[j]);
    }
    return strBuffer.toString();
}
```

- Split complete string on basis of space
- Then convert each string to character array and reverse
  individual word.

Answer (score -1):

It's been a long time since I've touch Java, but here's the algorithm.

```
String stringToReverse = "This is a Test";
String finalString = "";
Stack word = new Stack;
for(int i = 0; i < stringToReverse.length; i++){
    char chr = stringToReverse[i];
    if(chr == " " || i == (stringToReverse.length - 1)){
        while(word.count > 0){
            finalString += word.pop();
        }
         finalString += chr;
    }else{
        word.push(chr);
    }
}
```

Comment: to whom that voted down on this please explain your reason behind it so I could learn a thing or two from you?

Comment: I don't know about the downvoter but your code doesn't compile, there are multiple syntax errors in it. It's usually a good idea to compile your code before posting it as an answer.

Comment: I didn't said it's code, I said Algorithm. which means it's pseudo code.